# Sprite Kit - Adding two physics bodies to one SKNode

Tags: ios7, physics, sprite-kit

Is it possible to add two (ore more) SKPhysicsBodys to one SKNode? Something similar to this:
[Example from PhysicsEditor](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48105952/pic.png)
Because the head of the character should collide with a ball, the top should be round. Furthermore the ball mustn't go through the player. Do you have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use **+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithBodies:** method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [`physicsBody` property on `SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/physicsBody) suggests, there's a one-to-one relationship between nodes and physics bodies.

However, that doesn't mean you have to have one basic shape for every visible sprite. There are a few approaches you can take to accomplish what you're looking for:

- Does the top really need to be rounded? You can cover most of the monkey art with a rectangle. (I presume you want a rounded top so collisions bounce in different directions, though.)
- Create the "round-ended-rectangle" shape you're after using a polygon. You'll have to pick a number of sides for approximating the curve that fits your app: too many and it'll slow down the physics simulation, too few and it won't behave like a circle when other bodies bounce off.
- Every body needs a node, but not every node needs a visible sprite. You can make your monkey out of two nodes: one that holds the art and has the square or round physics body attached, and another node that has the other physics body, attached through a fixed joint, 
  but with no art.

Comment: Just a note, iOS 8 now lets you add two physics bodies to one SKNode using bodyWithBodies:, as in SKPhysicsBody.bodyWithBodies(bodies: AnyObject[]?). Note that properties on the child bodies, such as mass or friction, are ignored. Only the shapes of the child bodies are used. If you need a node with multiple hit targets (e.g. body vs head) then you need to do what rickter suggests in bullet point #3.

Comment: This is not true, you can set multiple bodies with **+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithBodies:** method

Answer (score 3):

This is the top hit on Google for this question so i thought I'd update the answers. This is possible (Although may not have been in 2013), as per the answer from Mike S in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178390/sprite-kit-one-node-with-two-physics-body).

You need to use

```
// Swift
SKPhysicsBody(bodies: <#[AnyObject]#>) 

// Obj-c
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:(NSArray *)bodies]
```

So you create a body with other bodies and add that one body to your `SKnode`.

Answer (score 0):

No, every `SKNode` can only have one `SKPhysicsBody` since `physicsBody` is a single property of `SKNode`. Like [rickster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster) said, your first option is to make the monkey one silo-shaped physics body using the `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:` class method of `SKPhysicsBody`.

Your other option is to create two separate `SKNodes` and attach them with an `SKPhysicsJointFixed`. [rickster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster)'s answer is great, but I just wanted to give the class names in case you want to do a little Googling around.