# merge two sprite nodes in sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am designing a sprite kit game where I want to merge two sprite nodes (rect shapes) together and then act and move them as one sprite node ?

I've been searching lot and I didn't find results

Is that possible in sprite kit ? and how can I do it ?

I'll appreciate any help, Thanks

Comment: Create an SKNode and then add the two sprites to the node using addChild.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how can I run SKAction on parent,
lets say I defined SKNode *blocks;
and I added the tow blocks to the same parent
[blocks addChild: firstBlock];
[blocks addChild: secondBlock];

when I apply an SKAction to the parent:
[blocks runAction moveOneStep];
nothing moves !!
shouldn't both blocks move ?
So what is the problem ?

Comment: How is moveOneStep defined?

Answer (score 1):

Add one node as a child of the other. If you set it's `node2.physicsbody.dynamic=NO;` it will move as a single node.  There will be separate physicsbodies but you can set them to the same category bitmask.

The answer linked here may help with notation: [How to detect contact on different areas of a physicsbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637025/how-to-detect-contact-on-different-areas-of-a-physicsbody)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how can I run SKAction on parent,
lets say I defined SKNode *blocks;
and I added the tow blocks to the same parent
[blocks addChild: firstBlock];
[blocks addChild: secondBlock];

when I apply an SKAction to the parent:
[blocks runAction moveOneStep];
nothing moves !!
shouldn't both blocks move ?
So what is the problem ?

Comment: I have the code from the answer I linked working.  Does your *blocks node move without the two blocks added as children?  I'm not sure if this helps but maybe try using spritenodes, not just nodes.

Comment: Have you looked into SKPhysicsJoint ? You can join two physics bodies together if you use a SKPhysicsJointFixed when you move one the other one will follow.
Everything else could be edited using various properties. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJoint_Ref/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sprite nodes, you simply do this :

```
[firstSprite addChild:secondSprite]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how can I run SKAction on parent,
lets say I defined SKNode *blocks;
and I added the tow blocks to the same parent
[blocks addChild: firstBlock];
[blocks addChild: secondBlock];

when I apply an SKAction to the parent:
[blocks runAction moveOneStep];
nothing moves !!
shouldn't both blocks move ?
So what is the problem ?

Comment: Also, you should start a new question, as this one doesn't mention a SKAction at all. If you are using physics, there's some potential issues there. But how can we help if you don't explain it fully and post relevant code ?

Comment: Thanks, I will add link to Xcode project to new question

Comment: thank you,
the new question with link to Xcode project:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088617/merge-two-sprite-nodes

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with which I have achieved what you are looking for using SpriteKit (Swift)

- First apply Physics to your scene

Example:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        sceneBody.friction = 1
        self.physicsBody = sceneBody
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boarder
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Item
```

- Second, Apply Physics to the two skspritenode's that you want to join together

Example

```
func mySpritetie1() {
        spritetie1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "img1")
        spritetie1.name = kAnimalNodeName
        spritetie1.position  = CGPoint(x: 170, y: 35)
        spritetie1.size = CGSizeMake(36, 100)
        spritetie1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(22, 100))
        spritetie1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        spritetie1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Item
        spritetie1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boarder
        spritetie1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
        self.addChild(spritetie1)
    }


    func mySpritetie2() {
        spritetie2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "img2")
        spritetie2.name = kAnimalNodeName
        spritetie2.position  = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 60)
        spritetie2.size = CGSizeMake(90, 79)

        spritetie2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
        spritetie2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        spritetie2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Item
        spritetie2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boarder
        spritetie2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
        self.addChild(spritetie2)
    }
```

- Third, now joining them

Example

```
let joint  = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(spritetie1.physicsBody!, bodyB: spritetie2.physicsBody!,
                    anchor: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(spritetie1.frame), CGRectGetMinY(spritetie2.frame)))

self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
```

This will join the two body at the anchor point you give.

Now you can animate any one of that (spritetie1 or spritetie2) using SKAction and the other will animate as if they are one and the same joined at the anchor point you defined.

If you feel this answer helped please do approve it. Hope it will help someone out there.

Please use this two link to learn about all thats in my code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

A very basic and good tutorial to learn about simulating physics https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa41xEuH5n_pwuNm7Z3L5qxDhVE0sOEqb

Thanks