# Sprite Kit: One node with two physics body

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

It's possible for one node to have two physics body paths? I want to create a node that has two (circle) physics bodies on the sides of the node.

If it's not possible, is there are any workaround to achieve that? thank you

[image]

Comment: Having one node with two childNodes, each with their own physics body perhaps?

Comment: ok, i will try it, hope that will solves my problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use `[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:...]`.  From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013032-CH1-SW46) :

> The shapes of the physics bodies passed into this method are used to
>   create a new physics body whose covered area is the union of the areas
>   of its children. These areas do not need to be contiguous. If there is
>   space between two parts, other bodies may be able to pass between
>   these parts. However, the physics body is treated as a single
>   connected body, meaning that a force or impulse applied to the body
>   affects all of the pieces as if they were held together with an
>   indestructible frame.

It would look something like this :

```
SKPhysicsBody *leftCircle = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:leftCircleRadius center:leftCircleCenter];
SKPhysicsBody *rightCircle = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:rightCircleRadius center:rightCircleCenter];

node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[leftCircle, rightCircle]];
```

Comment: can these paths overlap? like a circle with center at { 0 , 0 } radius 10 and another separate circle body with the same center origin location but radius of 20?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to connect to sprite nodes using SKPhysicsJointFixed. First, create two sprites:

```
    SKSpriteNode *sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(64, 64)];
    // position must be set before creating physics body to avoid bug in iOS 7.0.x
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    sprite1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite1.size];
    sprite1.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;

    [self addChild:sprite1];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(64, 64)];
    sprite2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-sprite2.size.width*2,
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    sprite2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite2.size];
    sprite2.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;

    [self addChild:sprite2];
```

then connect the nodes by calling this method:

```
    [self connectNode1:sprite1 toNode2:sprite2];
```

This method joins two nodes at their midpoint. Note that both physic bodies must be in the scene prior to calling this method.

```
- (void) connectNode1:(SKSpriteNode *)node1 toNode2:(SKSpriteNode *)node2
{
    CGPoint midPoint = CGPointMake((node1.position.x + node2.position.x)/2,
                    (node1.position.y + node2.position.y)/2);

    SKPhysicsJointFixed *joint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:node1.physicsBody
                                                               bodyB:node2.physicsBody
                                                              anchor:midPoint];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
}
```

Comment: thanks ! this one is working too. but Mike S answer is simpler, one node with two physics body, so I pick his answer as accepted answer. but again thanks !

Comment: I agree...that's a very good solution. bodyWithBodies is only available in iOS 7.1+, so it won't work if your deployment target is 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to achieve the behavior you are looking for:

[How to detect contact on different areas of a physicsbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637025/how-to-detect-contact-on-different-areas-of-a-physicsbody)

```
//Create SpriteNode1 & physicsBody
//Create SpriteNode2 & physicsBody
[SpriteNode1 addChild: SpriteNode2]
```

You can position SpriteNode2 relative to SpriteNode1.  Any movement, etc. performed on SpriteNode1 will also move SpriteNode2.

Set: `SpriteNode2.PhysicsBody.Dynamic=NO;`

You could also create a SpriteNode that acts as the main object and add both SN1 and SN2 as children if you find that easier.

Comment: This only works if only one node has a physicsBody. The OP wants two physics bodies.

Comment: Each SpriteNode has its own physics body.  That would make 2 physicsBodies total.  You can set them to be the same categoryBitMask or different.  This is how I create a headshot effect.  My head and body have different physicsBodies but the head is a child of the body.

Comment: How do you move the parent/child sprites in your game? If you apply a force to one physics body, the other will not move with it.

Comment: Set Dynamic=NO on the children node.  You are right, I should have included that.

Comment: I've tried this answer, and it's not working. if `childNode.physicsBody.dynamic` value is `NO`, the child won't even move

Comment: Try Pinned=Yes to fix position relative to parent.  I do not have my syntax right now.  I will update you when I have access to it later today.  Use the link to find further examples.  It definitely works it is just a matter of calling the proper statements in the proper order.